# PostgreSQL is inserting the default timestamp but with another timezone

Tags: java, eclipselink, postgresql-9.4

I have a Java Desktop app with Eclipselink, which insert some event (logs), this log is mapped by:

```
@Entity
public class ClientLog {
@Column(nullable=false, lenght=200)
private String description;
@Column(nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false, columnDefinition = "timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now()")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date systemDate;

}
```

the column definition is

```
systemdate timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
```

Recently they re-installed the pc and the region was set wrongly, I thought (I was very sure about it) this wouldn't affect the soft because the only thing the app does is insert logs sending the `description` column but I was wrong, `systemdate` is being inserted with the **timeZone of this pc** instead of the server, like 4 hours later, even when the pc has the time right.

In the entity ClientLog, systemDate is not even set, it is always `null`.

What is happening here? the ORM shouldn't send or affect this insertion in any way, the server should provide/complete the value of the column based on the config on it

Comment: Is the database running on a remote machine ? Because it will use the time on that machine when defaulting the field

Comment: yeap, the server is in another

Comment: Turn on logging (https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging) to see the SQL generated, but if the field is insertable/updatable=false, it shouldn't be in the SQL so entirely set by your DB.  How are you checking the timezone?  Date doesn't have one, so if you are reading it back, it will always be in the local time

Comment: I did that and it doesn't send the paramater/column `INSERT INTO CLIENTELOG (ESTADO, CLIENTE_ID, SUCURSAL_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?)`
 bind => [2, 1, 1]

but somehow, the server is "receiving" the diff timezone from clients apps and setting the column with it

Comment: How are you verifying that? Are you checking the value that is in the database on the DB server machine?

Comment: ...of course that I am seeing the values in the DB and in the applications too, that's when others users (in others pc) noticed some "futuristic" logs and report me the bug, ex: server current_time 00:30, value inserted  03:30, users see 03:30